# How can I scale everything on a screen depending on the size of monitor?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in Python and Pygame, and I made all the sprites and backgrounds to fit in my 1334 x 800 monitor in `FULLSCREEN` mode.  But if I run it on a smaller monitor, my images are still the same size, making the sprites and images get cut off.

How can I scale everything so that the sprites and images fit a smaller or bigger screen?

For example:

```
import pygame
import sys

display = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
#IMAGE SIZE IS 100X100
image = pygame.image.load('Character.png')
x = 500
y = 500
while True:
    display.blit(image,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

How would I adjust the size of the character image to better accommodate the smaller or bigger screen?

Comment: ya im somewhat new to useing this site and i didnt know how to close the question or just delete sorry i wont do it again @KevinJ.Chase

Comment: Not a real problem.  FWIW, I would have considered this question worthy of an upvote if it didn't already have an answer.